# SQL Select command to ignore until a condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been writing a site (using ASP) that displays data from tables that have a time stamp from 6pm the previous day till the page is loaded.

This I've done.

But to improve on this, I want only the records that occur after a specific record, that has a certain condition. So ignoring everything before that specific record occurs in the select statement (which is ordered by time stamp).

I'm pretty much lost.

Here's my SQL select, any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT M.ProductionID, M.FolderNo, M.SetDatetime, M.MessageNumber, 
       M.MessageText, M.MessageLocation, MD.GrossCopies, MD.NetCopies,
       MD.Speed 
FROM   ST3ROTE_Message AS M 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ST3ROTE_MessageData AS MD 
             ON M.MessageID = MD.MessageID 
WHERE  M.FolderNo = @DropSelect 
AND    (M.SetDatetime BETWEEN 
           CONVERT (DateTime, CONVERT (nchar(4), DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())) 
                 + '-' + CONVERT (nchar(2), DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())) 
                 + '-' + CONVERT (nchar(2), DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) - 1)
                 + ' 18:00:00') AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
ORDER BY M.MessageID
```

Here is the data I currently get:

[image]

I'm looking to ignore everything before MessageNumber = 27

Comment: Which is the specific condition you are looking for? Is it the `M.FolderNo = @DropSelect` or does that always have to be checked, and are you talking about another condition. It would be helpful if you would provide example data, and expected output.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying so quickly. I was wanting to display everything after M.MessageNumber=27 .. The @DropSelect is only a dropdown so i can select the correct Folder (basically the M.FolderNo)

Comment: @trincot I cant post example data on here.. its too much to enter here.. but ive taken a screenshot. [link](http://www.neebong.co.uk/files/events.png).. Im looking to ignore everything before MessageNumber = 27

Comment: This looks like your data has events, so *SetDateTime* can never be later than now. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first select the time of the first record with the special condition, in a sub-select (I put it in a `with` clause). This would return exactly one record per Folder. And then select all records for the same folder that have a time stamp that is not less than that one:

```
WITH StartRec AS ( 
    SELECT  FolderNo, MIN(SetDatetime) SetDatetime
    FROM    ST3ROTE_Message
    WHERE   FolderNo = @DropSelect
        AND MessageNumber = 27 -- your starting condition
        AND SetDatetime BETWEEN 
              DATEADD(hour, 18, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE())) 
              AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    GROUP BY FolderNo)
SELECT     M.ProductionID, M.FolderNo, M.SetDatetime, 
           M.MessageNumber, M.MessageText, M.MessageLocation, 
           MD.GrossCopies, MD.NetCopies, MD.Speed 
FROM       ST3ROTE_Message AS M
INNER JOIN StartRec
        ON StartRec.FolderNo = M.FolderNo 
       AND StartRec.SetDatetime <= M.SetDatetime
LEFT JOIN  ST3ROTE_MessageData AS MD
        ON M.MessageID = MD.MessageID 
WHERE      M.FolderNo = @DropSelect
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b781c/10). Note that since the fiddle works with few data, it will not return any records if executed after today.

Also note that your way of calculating "yesterday at 18:00" can be done a lot more efficient, as I have included in the query above:

```
DATEADD(hour, 18, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()))
```

This first calculates the number of whole days between day 1 (earliest date has value 0) and now. Then this is used as a date (= yesterday 0:00) to which 18 hours are added.

Since you said in comments that *SetDateTime* reflects the timestamp of an event that happened, and can never be a time in the future, you don't really need a `BETWEEN` condition for. You could replace:

```
        SetDatetime BETWEEN 
          DATEADD(hour, 18, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE())) 
          AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

By:

```
        SetDatetime >= DATEADD(hour, 18, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: This works brilliantly! I would never worked that out! Thank you for all your help(and editing my question so it made sense) @trincot